# How do I backup and restore a database using sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Database of 50Gb of data on Test Server A, I want to take the Backup and I want to Restore it to Test Server B. I need Backup and Restore step by step with query's?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure, start with these MSDN how-tos

- [How to: Back Up a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)
- [How to: Restore a Database Backup (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)

You'll need to copy the backup file from serverA to serverB of course.

SSMS will allow you to script these actions too so you can see teh underlying SQL commands

Answer (score 0):

use mysqldump if you are using MySql db
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

for export

```
mysqldump --opt --user=root --password test dbname > dbbackupscript.sql
```

for import

```
mysqldump --opt --user=root --password test dbname < dbbackupscript.sql
```

Comment: Question was tagged sql-server

Comment: Tell me as A SQL DBA how to do?

Comment: am a BEGINNER of SQL SERVER DBA. So I need a step by step procedure to take backup and restore process on Test Server.